# Remove Color from Scoll Bars

Tags: html, css

I have a css code, somewhere in the code the scroll bars have turned green how do i remove the color i do not know if it is the body .

https://filebin.net/wyvcirmysal7g4z2

Comment: Check the `.scroller` class styles,` body` styles and styles applied to `::-webkit-scrollbar` . According to me, these are the only three sections where you are applying any styles to the scrollbar.

Comment: The typical procedure would locate any instances of green and try to disable them until you found what made the scrollbars green. Then, if you still don't understand why, ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your style and the only green thing I found was for the background for the body tag.
But if you want to change the scroller you can add these styles as an example.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #bd3030;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #8a3939;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```